# Binary Tree Traversal Sum Of Each Depth

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I am looking for an algorithm or modification of an efficient way to get the sum of run through of a tree depth, for example:

```
                Z
               / \
              /   \
             /     \
            /       \
           X         Y
          / \      /  \
         /   \    /    \
        A     B  C      D
```

The number of final leaves is four so us have four final sums and they would be this respectively.

[Z+X+A] [Z+X+B] [Z+Y+C] [Z+Y+D]

If someone could guide me in the right direction into getting the sums of all possible depths, that would be great.

This will be done in python with fairly large trees.

Comment: you want to look for an efficient dfs algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You can recurse over the nodes of the tree keeping the sum from the root down to this point. When you reach a leaf node, you return the current sum in a list of one element. In the internal nodes, you concatenate the lists returned from children.

Sample Code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

def tree_sums(root, current_sum):
    current_sum += root.value
    if len(root.children) == 0:
        return [current_sum]
    subtree_sums = []
    for child in root.children:
        subtree_sums += tree_sums(child, current_sum)
    return subtree_sums

tree = Node(1, [Node(2, []), Node(3, [])])
assert tree_sums(tree, 0) == [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for.  In this example, trees are stored as dicts with a "value" and a "children" keys, and "children" maps to a list.

```
def triesum(t):
    if not t['children']:
        return [t['value']]
    return [t['value'] + n for c in t['children'] for n in triesum(c)]
```

Example

```
trie = {'value': 5, 'children': [
    {'value': 7, 'children': [
        {'value': 8, 'children': []},
        {'value': 2, 'children': []}
    ]},
    {'value': 4, 'children': [
        {'value': 3, 'children': []},
        {'value': 6, 'children': []}
    ]}
]}

print sorted(triesum(trie)) == sorted([5 + 7 + 8, 5 + 7 + 2, 5 + 4 + 3, 5 + 4 + 6])
    # prints True
```

Comment: Excellent could you provide me with an example tree dict that could be inputted to the algo?

Comment: added the example I used to test it

Comment: I gave you the most pythonic answer, but because it visits children that are None, you will have twice as many sums.  This was obfuscated during testing when I used sets instead of lists.  You may be more interested in an answer that isn't a one-liner, but doesn't visit None children

Comment: How does it give twice as many sums as expected? If the example prints true that's what I want right?

Comment: In your example, if node X has value 5, A and B have value None, then ideally, the subtree would return [5], but in my algorithm it would return [5 + 0, 5 + 0] because of the basecase.  The algorithm will therefore uniformly add duplicates on balanced trees.  When I type convert to set, the duplicates are lost, so it looks like the ideal answer.  This is hard to explain in a comment, so let me know if this doesn't make sense and we can move the conversation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67442/discussion-between-dom-farolino-and-twinlakes).