# Turning Multidimensional List Into Tree Python

Tags: python, algorithm, multidimensional-array, tree

I am trying to make some code that will take a multidimensional list and turn it into a dictionary tree.

The multi-dimensional list may be like this.

```
x = [[0,2,5],[1,1,3],[2,1,1]]
```

The list will always represent an NxN grid. Picture it like this.

```
0 2 5
1 1 3
2 1 1
```

Starting at the top left you can go only right or down from node to node to find its children.

```
So 0 would have children of 2 and 1
    2 would have children of 5 and 1
        5 would have children of ...
        1 would have children of ...
    1 would have children of 1 and 2
        1 would have children of ...
        2 would have children of ...
```

So the tree for this would like this:

```
                                           0
                                         /    \
                                        /      \
                                       /        \
                                      /          \
                                     /            \
                                    2             1
                                   /\             /\
                                  /  \           /  \
                                 /    \         /    \
                                1      5       2      1
                               /\      |       |      /\
                              /  \     |       |     /  \
                             1   3     3       1    3    1
                             |   |     |       |    |    |
                             1   1     1       1    1    1
```

This is what a visual tree would look like of the nodes and their children and it would be represented by code in this structure:

```
 tree = {'value': 0, 'children': [
            {'value': 2, 'children': [
                {'value': 1, 'children': [
                    {'value': 1, 'children': [
                        {'value': 1, 'children': [None, None]}
                    ]},
                    {'value': 3, 'children': [
                        {'value': 1, 'children': [None, None]}
                    ]}
                ]},
                {'value': 5, 'children': [
                    {'value': 3, 'children': [
                        {'value': 1, 'children': [None, None]}
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]},
            {'value': 1, 'children': [
                {'value': 1, 'children': [
                    {'value': 3, 'children': [
                        {'value': 1, 'children': [None, None]}
                    ]},
                    {'value': 1, 'children': [
                        {'value': 1, 'children': [None, None]}
                    ]}
                ]},
                {'value': 2, 'children': [
                    {'value': 1, 'children': [
                        {'value': 1, 'children': [None, None]}
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]}
```

If there is any efficient way to turn the aforementioned grid into this shapely dictionary guidance in the right direction would be very helpful. I have tried this: http://repl.it/6sU with no luck as the recursion was too deep however I cannot think of a different way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to turn a semi-compact encoding of a matrix into this hideous tree structure?  Why not just store it as a matrix?  You could even use NumPy.

Comment: Bhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595162/binary-tree-traversal-sum-of-each-depth/27595260 This is my other question regarding taking the written structure and turning it into a list of sums. I am trying to take the multi dimensional list and calculate each possible sum of digits going from top left to bottom right

Comment: Are you doing this to find the smallest sum, largest sum, or some other reason?

Comment: To find a sum closest to a given #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post a solution to the actual problem you have, which as you mention in a comment is to find the sum closest to a given number, where the candidate sums are found by traversing an NxN matrix by moving only down and right.

```
def gridsums(grid, x, y, memo):
    if memo[x][y] is not None:
        return memo[x][y]

    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        sums = [0]
    elif x == 0:
        sums = gridsums(grid, x, y-1, memo)
    elif y == 0:
        sums = gridsums(grid, x-1, y, memo)
    else:
        sums = gridsums(grid, x-1, y, memo) + gridsums(grid, x, y-1, memo)

    sums = [grid[x][y] + s for s in sums]
    memo[x][y] = sums
    return sums

def gridsumsfast(grid):
    memo = []
    for row in grid:
        memo.append([])
        for cell in row:
            memo[-1].append(None)

    return gridsums(grid, len(grid[0]) - 1, len(grid) - 1, memo)
```

The simplest version is to completely delete the "memo" stuff, but that implements "dynamic programming" to cache previously-computed results and avoid duplicate work.  The rest is a fairly straightforward recursive solution which directly produces all the possible sums (including duplicates).

For your example data, the result is `[11, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5]`.

Comment: I'm foolish for making it way more complicated than it needs to be thank you

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer solves your problem, please "accept" it by ticking the checkmark on the left, below the up and down voting buttons.

Comment: Yes I know I just hadn't got it yet, will do, thank you

Comment: Turns out for the size of data I am using, (20 rows with 20 numbers in each) the algo has memory errors. Could you explain how to implement dynamic programming in this setting so that the gridsum is not repeating too much work?

Comment: What do you mean "has memory errors?"  Try without the dynamic programming part--simply delete all the "memo" parts.  The algorithm should still work.  If not, perhaps it is a problem with recursion depth, but you haven't posted your error message....